# Android app ported to Chromium OS using ARC Welder won't launch anymore; launches in ARC

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc, chromium-os

While attempting to port my Android app, [New Daily Quotes](http://www.thevgc.net/new-daily-quotes), to Chrome OS and Chromium OS using Google's [ARC Welder](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) tool, my application will launch perfectly fine in the ARC envinronment, but as soon as I publish to the Chrome Web Store and install on my Dell Inspiron 1525 running Chromium OS 46.0.2462.0 (64-bit), it simply refuses to load.

Checking the *Developer Options* box in the Extensions page and then checking the *Collect errors* box brings up the following log information:

```
* File system is initialized.
* Compositor is enabled
! Plugin not ready
* NativeClient: Nexe crashed during startup
* retry to spawn with timeout 4sec.
* retry to spawn with timeout 16sec.
* timeout to spawn ChildPlugin process: umareporter(so_executable), umareporter bool
  ArcRuntime.ShutdownIsCrash false longtime ArcRuntime.Uptime 41157 enumeration
  ArcRuntime.LastBootStep 1 6
* retry to spawn with timeout 32sec.
* NativeClient: Nexe crashed during startup
* timeout to spawn ChildPlugin process: umareporter(so_executable), umareporter bool
  ArcRuntime.DexopInterrupted false
! give up to spawn ChildPlugin process
```

I really have no idea what's going on here, but any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Google has not (as least not yet) opened the Chrome Web Store for installing to other OSes but Chrome OS.

Comment: It's available in Chromium OS, which is what I'm trying to run my app through.

Comment: @DarkWolffe: Aha, I missed that. Sorry.